# jhipster ssl ubuntu apache2 setup

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, apache2, ubuntu-16.04, jhipster

I have generated my app using Jhipster. Configured it to run on amazon ec2 with Ubuntu 16.x and apache with following configuration and godaddy a record. When I hit the website url it maps and renders the site without any issues.

apache2 configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 111.22.33.444
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / http://111.22.33.444:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://111.22.33.444:8080/

</VirtualHost>
```

Nest step, trying to configure SSL. I have bought the SSL from godaddy for my domain, configured it and uploaded the *.crt files into /etc/apache2/ssl. I quickly realized just by adding another virtual host configuration for port 443 will not work because JHipster app is running on 8080. I went back and looked at https://www.jhipster.tech/production/ and they have instructions for configuring SSL with **HTTPS configuration with a front-end proxy** and this where I got lost and am unable to configure SSL and serve up my domain on https.

What is not clear is can I still run the app on 8080 and simply follow the instructions under **HTTPS configuration with a front-end proxy**? First, I configured apache using "lets encrypt" using the following command

```
sudo certbot --apache -d doamin.com --agree-tos -m info@domain.com --redirect
```

it failed saying

Failed redirect for domain.com

Unable to set enhancement redirect for domain.com

It didn't work.

What are the changes for Jhipster application that I need to do? Should it run on 443 or continue to run 8080 and update virtual host configuration? How should i configure virtual host?

I have searched high and low with no instructions. Any direction is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried lets-encrypt without the --redirect parameter?  I'm guessing it fails because you don't have any hosts declared in your existing virtual host (or maybe you removed them?).  Your setup looks correct (http request -> apache -> jhipster app)

Comment: @JonRuddell Thank you for the response. You are right that I don't have any hosts declared in my virtual host. I tried different combinations including lets encrypt with no luck. Even though lets-encrypt gives error message it does update the virtual-host entry for 443. My question is can i run the app on 8080 and still configure HTTPS? If so, what should be the apache configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your app is available at http://127.0.0.1:8080/, you can successfully configure Apache for HTTPS with Certbot by following the below steps.

Setup server with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-certbot-apache apache2
```

Start with the config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias example.com

        ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/

        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyRequests Off

</VirtualHost>
```

Enable plugins and restart Apache2, making the app accessible at the domain configured above:

```
a2enmod headers proxy proxy_http
service apache2 restart
```

Then run certbot with [the instructions in the docs](https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntuxenial-apache.html):

```
sudo certbot --apache -d example.com
```

After that, your app will be accessible at the domain you configured and served via HTTPS.